# Emulador Cloud Firestore não está rodando corretamente

Tags: banco-de-dados, typescript, firebase

Estou testando uma requisição 'post' para ‘login’ no banco firebase usando o emulador 'cloud firestore' com o comando ***firebase serve*** no terminal e a resposta esperada no 'postman' seria um 'token' para autenticação de usuário em algumas requisições que necessitam de validação, o bug que ocorreu comigo hoje é que o emulador simplesmente não acessa mais o banco mesmo estando tudo aparentemente igual.

Quando utilizo o comando

```
**firebase serve**
```

A minha aplicação abre a o caminho API local [http://localhost:5000/nome-daaplicação/us-east1/api/login](http://localhost:5000/nome-daaplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o/us-east1/api/login)

Quando eu insiro a seguinte requisição:

```js
{
   "login": "user@email.com", 
   "password": "123456"
}
```

O retorno no postmam é código 500 *Error: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.*

O meu terminal me retorna a seguinte mensagem: *The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.*

No código abaixo está minha requisição com sua respectiva lógica.

```
const login = (_req: any, _res: any) => {
    const user: LoginUser = {
        email: _req.body.email,
        password: _req.body.password
    }

    const isValid: IsValid = validateLoginData(user)

    if(!isValid.valid) return _res.status(400).json(isValid.errors)

    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then((data: any) => {
            return data.user.getIdToken()
        })
        .then((token) => {
            return _res.json({ token })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)            
            return _res
                .status(403)
                .json({ general: 'Wrong credentials, please try again' })
        })
}
```

Essa requisição utiliza o firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword que retorna uma promise do firebase.user.getIdToken que vai me retornar um JSON com o Token que me permita fazer requisições que necessitem estar autenticado.

Ao investigar o problema em documentações cheguei a seguinte solução no Stack Overflow em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125151/firestore-local-http-with-real-db-the-cloud-firestore-emulator-is-not-running-s

E eu a implementei utilizando o comando no windows:
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Project\project-name\functions\serviceaccountkey.json"

após isso alterei o código de inicialização do firebase para:

```
admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
 });
```

Após isso mesmo iniciando o firebase com ***firebase serve*** ou firebase ***emulators:start*** o meu servidor continua não enviando resposta para minha requisição.

Esta requisição antes funcionava e agora não funciona mais e mesmo usando ***firebase deploy*** a api também não responde requisição feita diretamente ao servidor.

Estou tentando encontrar o bug que possa estar ocasionando esse erro mas não sei mais onde procurar. Se alguém já passou por esse mesmo erro eu gostaria de receber um feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Você instalou o angular/fire?

https://github.com/angular/angularfire

A própria biblioteca se encarrega de adicionar o token, segue o código que eu utilizo:

```
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) { }

  public login(eMail: string, password: string): Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential> {
    return this.angularFireAuth
    .auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(eMail, password);
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.angularFireAuth
      .auth
      .signOut();   
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
}
```